# Sql to update login id's dynamically based on count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. One is main table and other one is login table. I may have 10 Records in Main table and 6 Records in login table. Each login id has to be assingned equally to main table. Can any one please give me the best solution to update the login information.

Example

```
Create table ##t1 
(id int identity,
name varchar(5),
loginid varchar(10)
divno char(3))




create table ##l1
(
id int identity,
name varchar(10),divno char(3))

insert into ##t1 values
('Jin',null,'001')
insert into ##t1 values
('Anu',null,'001')
insert into ##t1 values
('kir',null'002')
insert into ##t1 values
('Asi',null,'003')
insert into ##t1 values
('Nil',null,'002')
insert into ##t1 values
('sup',null,'003')
insert into ##t1 values
('amu',null,'003')
insert into ##t1 values
('mani',null,'003')

insert into ##l1 values
('A','001')
insert into ##l1 values
('B','001')
insert into ##l1 values
('C','002')
insert into ##l1 values
('D','002')
insert into ##l1 values
('E','002')
insert into ##l1 values
('F','003')
```

Data Example

```
Main table

id          name  loginid divno
----------- ----- ----------
1           Jin   NULL    001
2           Anu   NULL    001
3           kir   NULL    002
4           Asi   NULL    003
5           Nil   NULL    002
6           sup   NULL    003
7           amu   NULL    003
8           mani  NULL    003

Login Table

id          name    divno
----------- -------------
1           A        001
2           B        001
3           C        002
4           D        002
5           E        002
6           F        003
```

desired output

[image]

How can we do this without looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 update ##t1 
 set loginid = #l1.name
 from   
      ##t1
           inner join 
      (select *, (ROW_NUMBER() Over (order by id) -1)% (select COUNT(*) from ##l1)+1 as rn from ##t1) v
           on ##t1.id = v.id
           inner join 
      ##l1 
           on v.rn = ##l1.id
```

Comment: Thanks alot. One more question like what is that 6. My data will be dynamic. it has to be based on count.

Comment: Excellent. Appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @podiluska,one more change :( added one column in both tables. new column is divno which is char field. i need to update by joining these two also. how we will add that

Answer (score 0):

Let me do this as a select query rather than as an upadte.

```
select id, name, l.login
from (select mt.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) % l.loginCount) + 1 as loginSeqnum
      from MainTable mt cross join
           (select count(*) as loginCount from login) l
     ) mt join
     (select l.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from login l
     ) l
     on mt.LoginSeqnum = l.seqnum
```

What this is doing is adding a sequence number to the logins (just in case loginid is not 1..n.  It then calculates a similar value for each record in the first table.

One nice thing about this method is you can modify it to get more random orderings, by changing the "order by" clause in the row_number() statements.  For instance, using "order by newid()" will randomize the assignment, rather than doing it in a round-robin fashion.

Comment: your output is not picking the login id is in order

Comment: It starts with the second one, which is easily fixed by subtracting one from the row_number() in loginSeqnum.  Your original question did not specify that you wanted them in order, just "equally".